# Esconder todo menos tres <li> con nth

Tags: css

Estoy usando un listado que lo uso de paginación, y es tan larga que me gustaría ocultar todos salvo la anterior, actual y siguiente. Por ej:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>2</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>3</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>4</li>
    <li class="active">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>8</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>9</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>10</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
</ul>
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>2</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>3</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>4</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>5</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>6</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>7</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>8</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>9</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>10</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>11</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>12</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>13</li>
    <li class="active">14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>17</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>18</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>19</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>20</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>21</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>22</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>23</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>24</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>25</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
</ul>
```

¿Se puede con nth u otro selector?

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que combinar esto con javascript/jquery para que te pueda funcionar ya que css permite seleccionar el elemento hermano que esta después del DOM pero no el que está antes

Comment: eso se tiene que ser dinámico?, lo genera por un siclo for o solamente lo ingresas manual?

Comment: ¿Cómo asignas la clase "active" al `li`? ¿Se le asigna desde el servidor o desde el cliente con JS? ¿Cómo de flexible es el modo en que se asigna esa clase? (p.e. ¿se podría crear la clase `prev-active` en lugar de `active`?)

Comment: @tomillo, la acción pasa cuando haces click?, partes del primero siempre cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo mas rapido que se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

```js
$().ready(()=>{
  $('li:not(.active)').css('display','none');
  $active = $('li.active');
  $active.next().css('display','');
  $active.prev().css('display','');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>1</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>2</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>3</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>4</li>
    <li class="active">5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>8</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>9</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
    <li>10</li> <!-- Ocultar -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

Según te ejemplo de me ocurre de la siguiente manera , usaremos algunas propiedades de `jquery` y usaremos lo siguiente:

- `eq` que sirve para seleccionar un elemento como si fuera un array.
- `lt` que va ha seleccionar todos los elementos de una lista anteriores del elemento.
- `gt` que va ha seleccionar todos los elementos de una lista a partir de elemento que seleccionaremos con `click`
- `show` que lo usaremos para mostrar los elementos.
- `hide` que lo usaremos para ocultar los elementos.
- `index` que lo usaremos para obtener la posición actual.

***Con todo eso explicado vamos al resultado.!!!!***

```js
$("ul li").click(function(){
  
    $(this).addClass('active')
    var indice = $(this).index();
    if(indice == 0){
       $("ul li:eq("+(indice+1)+")").addClass("active").show();
       $("ul li:gt("+(indice+1)+")").removeClass("active").hide();
      
    }else{
      $("ul li:eq("+(indice+1)+")").addClass("active").show();
      $("ul li:eq("+(indice-1)+")").addClass("active").show();
    
      $("ul li:lt("+(indice-1)+")").removeClass("active").hide();
      $("ul li:gt("+(indice+1)+")").removeClass("active").hide();
    }
    
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>2</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>3</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>4</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>5</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>6</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>7</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>8</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>9</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>10</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>11</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>12</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>17</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>18</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>19</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>20</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>21</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>22</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>23</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>24</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
  <li>25</li>
  <!-- Ocultar -->
</ul>
```

Lo que importa realmente en el ejemplo es el ***jquery*** , donde primero obtendremos la posición de nuestro elemento usando la propiedad `index`, luego se lo asignamos a una variable para posterior hacer la lógica de seleccionar los elementos que están al costado y ocultar los demás. 
Explicado mas detallado, lo que obtengo es un numero al hacer `$(this).index();` , con ese numero digo que usando `eq` me seleccione los elementos al costado ya que la lista en jquery cree que es un array por lo tanto restará una posición y sumara una posición para permitirse seccionar.

Espero te sirva saludos!!!

Comment: Gracias Sebastián. Utilizaré el código de @Samir que son menos lineas.

Comment: no te preocupes , el que te sirva más usalo, es a tu gusto.

Answer (score 1):

Con **jQuery** ocultas todos los **li** antes y después del activo así:

```
$(".active").nextAll().hide();
$(".active").prevAll().hide();
```

Y después muestras solo el anterior y el siguiente así:

```
$(".active").next().show();
$(".active").prev().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

0
votar en contra

yo te recomendaria una etiqueta que ya existe quitando todos los li. Ademas es mucho mas rapido y creo que te puede servir, aunque no se de que va tu proyecto. la etiqueta details se despliega con un click.

```
<details>
 <summary>lo que vas a mostrar o lo que se ve </summary>
 <p>contenido oculto</p>
 <p>contenido oculto</p>
 <p>contenido oculto</p>
</details>
```

Alomejor es menos profesional, pero tambien depende como lo hagas en css y tal.Te recomendaria dividirlo en divs. un saludo.